Show window when global hotkey is pressed after app is terminated in Swift
I want app to listen to global hotkey in background even when app is terminated and show window when hotkey is pressed in Swift in macOS.
Here's my code now.
import HotKey
import SwiftUI

@main
struct SecureleaveApp: App {
    var hotKey = HotKey(key: .l, modifiers: [.command], keyDownHandler: {
        //Processing when hotkey is pressed
    })
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainView()
        }
    }
}

